# How to make light shine through a prism?

Tags: shaders, light

I'm trying to make a scene like this:

[image: Goal Scene]

But no matter how I mess with the bounce settings in cycles; the light just isn't coming out of the other side of the prism:

[image: Render Result]

[BlendFile](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/462248006180405271/729782157819510824/prism.blend)

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: See also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27805/whats-going-wrong-with-my-luxrender-prism

Comment: Cycles cannot  do this out of the box. Use Luxrender or other render engine.

Comment: No; the issue isn't the dispersion effect its the light not shining on the table on the other side of the prisim. I got cycles to do it breifly but when i tried to figure out what i did it stopped happening and i haven't been able to recreate it again.

Answer (score 1):

It was the "indirect light" in the "clamping" section of the "scene" properties tab.  It needs to be set to 0 for light to go through the prism.  I do not understand why it is so dark that that happens though.